# How to use FFMPEG commands

Tags: android, ffmpeg

In android i am making an app in which it will record an video and crop the video from center for doing so  i found FFMPEG over google. I followed   http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html

It works fine but i want to know how to use this `ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/short.mp4 -vf crop=100:100:0:0 -s 320x240 -r 15 -aspect 3:4 -ab 12288 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -sample_fmt s16 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4

` video cropping command and Where to write this command.

I have tried this (for concatenation just to check about how to use ffmpeg command )

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static native int logFileInfo(String[] args);
String pathOut = "/storage/sdcard/12.mp3";
String pathInM = "/storage/sdcard/23.mp3";
String pathIn = "/storage/sdcard/out.mp3";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] args = {"ffmpeg",  "-i", "concat:", pathOut, "|",pathInM ,pathIn};
    logFileInfo(args);
    //logFileInfo("/storage/sdcard/12.mp3");
}

static
{
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}
```

But i dont know what to write in mylib.c to execute this.somebody Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to spawn a process to run ffmpeg using ProcessBuilder:

```
Process ffmpeg = new ProcessBuilder().command(args).start()
if (ffmpeg.waitFor() != 0) {
    // handle failure case
}
```

(The above code blocks the current thread until ffmpeg finishes.)

However, I think your bigger issue would be having to cross-compile and distribute versions of ffmpeg for every device you're targeting.